# Typescript - Why does AxiosPromise not have a property ".finally"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I am converting a JS file over to TS. Here is the original code in question.

```
let refreshToken = null;

if (refreshToken == null) {
    refreshToken = // get the axios instance...
} 

refreshToken
.then(() => { // something })
.catch(() => { // something })
.finally(() => { // something });
```

So I converted it to:

```
let refreshToken : AxiosPromise | null = null;

if (refreshToken == null) {
    refreshToken = // get the axios instance...
} 

refreshToken
.then(() => { // something })
.catch(() => { // something })
.finally(() => { // something });
```

But the `finally` gives me an error:

> Property 'finally' does not exist on type Promise.

Why is that?

The way that I've gone around it is just write `(refreshToken as any)` but that seems like a cop-out solution. Shouldn't TypeScript be able to infer that `refreshToken` is an `AxiosPromise`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ npm install axios promise.prototype.finally --save
```

and add this to the top

```
require('promise.prototype.finally').shim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can append one more `.then` as last part of chain. Example with native Promise(this behaviour should be same) true/false as bellow:

```js
function fakeGet(passed) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(passed ? resolve : reject, 1000));
}

function onComplete(passed) {
  console.log(passed ? 'Success' : 'Failed')
}

fakeGet(true)
.then(() => true)
.catch(() => false)
.then(onComplete);

fakeGet(false)
.then(() => true)
.catch(() => false)
.then(onComplete);
```